# How to reverse and display the values in a text file in C++?

Tags: c++, reverse

The goal that I'm trying to do is be able to read/display the numbers in a file in the **reverse** order.

I made the code that does it in the normal order (and it does work), I just need to have the program **display the order in reverse.**

The file is just a text file with numbers in it.

Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

ifstream file("numbers.dat");
string content;

while(file >> content) {
cout << content << ' ';
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Store the things you read in a container. When you are done reading, reverse it, and then print it.

Comment: @DietmarKühl You are right; that's better, since the assignment doesn't require doing anything else with it.

Comment: @DietmarKuhl When I run the program 'as is', it displays the numbers as in the order that they're written. I need to have the numbers in the file displayed in the reverse order.

Comment: Does this assignment require a stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the numbers in file in a container and print from back to front.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::ifstream file("numbers.dat");
    std::string content;
    std::vector<std::string> numbers;

    while(file >> content) 
        numbers.push_back(content);
    for(int i = numbers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        std::cout << numbers[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```